# Querying existing table returns empty results

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying this neat framework (gorm) but I'm facing some issues with a basic read query.

What I`m doing is basically what the documentation says about how to read from a SQL Server database.

I got a database with a table `tests` (plural from the struct name `Test`). There is a single entry in the database (check the image), and I cannot retrieve it...

```
var server = "localhost"
var port = 1433
var user = "orm"
var password = "123localtest"
var database = "go"

var db *sql.DB

type Test struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

func main() {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d;database=%s",
        server, user, password, port, database)
    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", connectionString)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create connection pool. Error: " + err.Error())
    }
    gorm.DefaultCallback.Create().Remove("mssql:set_identity_insert")
    defer db.Close()

    tableExists := db.HasTable(&Test{})

    if tableExists {
        ReadFirstTest(db)
    }
}

// ReadFirstTest Gets and prints first Test from dbo.test
func ReadFirstTest(db *gorm.DB) {
    var test = Test{}

    db.First(&test)
    fmt.Printf("%d %s \n", test.ID, test.Name)

    db.Where("name = ?", "John").First(&test)
    fmt.Printf("%d %s \n", test.ID, test.Name)
}
```

Can you tell me what is missing here ?

[Database state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYVNY.png)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is `tableExists` true? Did you create the table manually or did you create it via `db.AutoMigrate(&Test{})`? Additionally, make sure you check for any potential errors when calling `db.First(&test)`, http://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html has a brief overview of how you should be able to do so.

Comment: The table is manually created, so no AutoMigrate has been invoked. `tableExists` is true and this code  `error := db.First(&test).Error fmt.Println(error)` returns no errors

Comment: Also this code  `db.Raw("select * from tests").Scan(&tests) fmt.Println(len(tests)) `prints 1(so there is an entry there)

Comment: I've found the problem the column names has been Capitalized so it couldnt be mapped - i guess. Once i've created the table with AutoMigrate and than mannually with lower cased letters it worked as a charm

Comment: If anyone wants to keep PascalCase database column naming conventions this annotation could help  `gorm:"type:int;column:Id"` or `gorm:"type:varchar(200);column:Name"`